# ASP.NET inject javascript in user control nested in update panel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, updatepanel, custom-server-controls

I'm trying to load javascript code with a user web control into a page via a the Page.LoadControl method during an asyncron post back of an update panel.

I've tried the specially for that scenario designed methods of the scriptmanager, but the javascript just doens't get returned to the user.

To explain my scenario a bit better:

Master Page has the script manager and one page loads the user control via Page.LoadControl-method during an async post back. The custom control injects in the pre-render event handler the javascript. Is that a matter of timing to inject the js or is it just not possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can do

```
string scr;
scr = "<script src='/scripts/myscript.js'></script>"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "key", scr, false)
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

**If you don't want to hard-code your JavaScript**, but instead include it from a file, call [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptinclude.aspx) and then call your initialization function in [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
      this, GetType(), "formatterScript", ResolveUrl("~/js/formatter.js"));
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
      this, GetType(), "formatTableFunction", "formatTable()", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your tried

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(GetType(Page), "key", <your script here>, addSctiptTags:=true)
```

We do this in our User Controls and it works for us

HTH

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RegisterStartupScript method of the ScriptManager class to inject executable script:

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{          
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), ClientID, "alert(1)", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am finding this only works with synchronous postbacks, not with asynchronous UpdatePanel-postbacks. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the RegisterStartupScript in the Page_PreRender event may not work if your control is nested in an asp.net modal popup. Instead, put it in the Page_Load when IsPostBack = False.